# API Call returns "Maximum call stack size exceeded" error

Tags: node.js, api, express, stripe-payments

I am trying to create an online payment service using Stripe and I would like to create an API endpoint using Express and Node.js such that my frontend server can call this API which will then handle charges for me in the backend. The following snippet is a POST API for what I have:

```
const express = require('express');
const router = express.Router();
const stripe = require('stripe')('sk_test_mystripescretkey');

router.post('/token', (req, res) => {
  stripe.tokens.create({
    card: req,
  }).then(token => res.send(token))
    .catch(err => res.status(400).send(err.message));
});
module.exports = router;
```

However, when I try to test this endpoint by calling it using Postman, I get a `Maximum call stack size exceeded` error. The stripe function by itself works fine, so I presume the error is coming from trying to call the stripe function inside an API endpoint? Could someone let me know why this error is occuring and maybe suggest a fix? Thank you.

Comment: Your code is probably recursing somewhere and you are getting a stack overflow in the browser. No pun intended.

Comment: @L0uis I presume it probably is a stack overflow, but I have no idea where the recursion could be. The stripe function itself is certainly not recursive by any means, and I am simply calling the endpoint from Postman.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're sending in the whole `req` as the argument in `stripe.tokens.create()`; you instead probably want to just send in the `req.body` (or the body parsed in some fashion, depending on what kind of data you're POSTing here).

Also you shouldn't be creating Tokens server-side like this - you should use Stripe.js for this: https://stripe.com/docs/js

Comment: Thank you, do you know how do I integrate the Stripe object? I have tried including the Strip.js script tags but I cannot access the Stripe object in my component class. I am working in Angular.

Comment: There's no official Angular guide, so I'd recommend just googling for one; something like this might work: https://www.devdungeon.com/content/using-stripejs-elements-angular